# Quicblox migration issue, No QBVideoChat class available

Tags: ios, objective-c, video-streaming, quickblox

I am getting this response in the log.
**There is no delegates which responds to didReceiveNewSession:userInfo:**

I wonder If this points to specific delegate as I am not able to find any relative solution for this.

Also Previously there was a class QBVideoChat which is not mentioned on Quickblox blog or updation guide.
I wonder if that has any thing to do with this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have same issue...Have you got any solutions.

Answer (score 1):

QuickBlox has deprecated old QBVideoChat with WebRTC QuickBloxWebRTC

http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-ios

Here is the open source sample-video-chat project available on github

https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk/tree/master/sample-videochat-webrtc

Error `There is no delegates which responds to didReceiveNewSession:userInfo:` means that you did not add any class to QBRTCClient delegates list

Comment: I used the latest sdk and QuickBloxWebRTC class.